# Element finding with repeated tags in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the html I have on a website:

```
<table class="table table-fixed table-header-right text-medium">
    <tbody><tr><th class="no-border">Certification Number</th><td class="no-border">48487270</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Label Type</th>
            <td>
                    <img width="69" height="38" class="margin-right-min" alt="" aria-hidden="true" src="https://i.psacard.com/psacard/images/cert/table-image-ink.png" style="">
                    <span class="inline-block padding-top-min">with fugitive ink technology</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr><th>Reverse Cert Number/Barcode</th><td>Yes</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Year</th><td>2020</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Brand</th><td>TOPPS</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Sport</th><td>BASEBALL CARDS</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Card Number</th><td>20</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Player</th><td>ARISTIDES AQUINO</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Variety/Pedigree</th><td></td></tr>

    <tr><th>Grade</th><td>NM-MT 8</td></tr>
                    </tbody></table>
```

I am trying to figure out a way to get and set the year to a variable, the normal way I find elements is with XPath but since these tags are repeated so many times with no other indicators I am unsure how to go about this. The year will change so I cant search by text. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup to find the `<th>` tag with the text `'Year'`. Then find the next `<td>` tag and extract the text from that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<table class="table table-fixed table-header-right text-medium">
    <tbody><tr><th class="no-border">Certification Number</th><td class="no-border">48487270</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Label Type</th>
            <td>
                    <img width="69" height="38" class="margin-right-min" alt="" aria-hidden="true" src="https://i.psacard.com/psacard/images/cert/table-image-ink.png" style="">
                    <span class="inline-block padding-top-min">with fugitive ink technology</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr><th>Reverse Cert Number/Barcode</th><td>Yes</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Year</th><td>2020</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Brand</th><td>TOPPS</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Sport</th><td>BASEBALL CARDS</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Card Number</th><td>20</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Player</th><td>ARISTIDES AQUINO</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Variety/Pedigree</th><td></td></tr>

    <tr><th>Grade</th><td>NM-MT 8</td></tr>
                    </tbody></table>'''
                    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
year = soup.find('th', text='Year').find_next('td').text

print(year)
```

**Output:**

```
'2020'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we need to find out webelements using driver.findelements function using that classname

And then we can get elements from that list

By `list.get(index)`

Or,
You can store all the td/th elements in a list and than search the list for  year you are looking for.